# iptables prerouting crashed smtp port

Tags: iptables, postfix, routing

I have a very strange problem. First of all. I have 2 servers

1. VDS server with (for instance) IP 100.11.100.22 (vpn ip: 10.8.0.1)
2. Server behind the VPN (ip: 10.8.0.7) with iredmail (postfix, devcot, etc)

And I routed all ports 143, 587, etc and all OK, but only 25 port does not work. What I do

1. If I do nothing, I can send email from 10.8.0.7 and telnet google.com 25 worked
2. But if I add code on the VDS server, I can't telnet google.com 25 (connection timed out) from my server behind VPN (only 1 string :( )

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.7:25
```

Forward and etc are ok, I think so because all ports are working. It doesn't work ONLY smtp port =\

Comment: Ok guys, after 3 days I've found problem. I need set the interface! Like that iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.7:25